# @media and @font-face support in LessCSS

Tags: css, less, media-queries

Hello does anyone know how to do a media query with LessCSS?

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      #container{
          width: 480px;
      }
  }
```

gives me the following error:

```
! Syntax Error: on line 23: expected one of :: : . # * - [ @media @font-face , { ; got ( after:

@media screen and
```

Similarly, @font-face and any CSS3 query with an @ conflict with LessCSS's compiler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I understand, LessCSS does not support @media, you may find open tickets for that on their github home page.

The only way I see for this to work in your case is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="smartphone.css" />
```

---

***It does look like the issue has been fixed in the LessCSS releases since the accepted answer.***

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I've heard that it is possible but nobody has been able to give an example. It's an easy workaround as you pointed out above, we could also just add a non-less css file, but that's not really the point of a bounty. :)

Comment: See @Colin's answer below. I can attest that LESS 1.5.5.js does support media queries out of the box in the sense that they're not stripped out. They just can't be used inside nested rules. So it depends on what you mean by 'support'.

Answer (score 37):

All of the answers above are out of date.

Both less.js and lessCss/dotless support @media and @font-face.

They also now support @media with nested rules, e.g.

```
.cl {
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .d {
   .e {
     background: none;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

becomes

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .cl .d .e {
   background: none;
 }
}
```

Please refer to the [less.js documentation](http://lesscss.org/) and [dotless documentation](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki) for more information.

Comment: Needs to come to the top, this is correct, lot of old ones above.

Comment: They may have added the feature, but neither of the projects linked make any reference to it in their current documentation. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @IMSop: http://lesscss.org/ now has a "Nested Media Queries" section under "The Language."

Answer (score 3):

If you can use [less.js](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js), it works right out of the box. I tried the same example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #container{
        width: 480px;
    }
}
```

and it reproduced it exactly the same in the .css file. There's also an escape functionality in less.js, but it only seems to work on values, so I don't think you could use it for this.

```
body {
    color: e('red');
}
```

I'm guessing that you're using the original Ruby LessCSS though? If you can't switch to the new one, the only other thing I can think of is using an @include. This might be slightly better than another link tag in the HTML, and if you compress all your CSS files, you might be able to avoid the extra HTTP request.

Comment: thanks Robbles, I have been complaining on LessCSS's site, looks like I am not the only one there with that wish. it turns out that parent selectors are also missing from the Ruby gem, but are available in the js version. And it seems like they gave up on the ruby gem...

Answer (score 2):

> LESS doesn’t currently provide any special support for media queries. This means that it’s impossible to embed media queries within LESS’s nested rules, forcing developers to silo their responsive styles in a separate section of the LESS document, rather than in keeping them in context. Let me give you an example of how it could work:

from [A Call for LESS to Embrace Responsive Design](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2011/02/07/a-call-for-less/)

So yes, you can use media queries right now but you cannot write them in the nested syntax.

Check out the comments on that blog post for some proposed solutions that look like they'll be rolled in less.js sooner than later.

Comment: +1 because you can use `@media` in a LESS stylesheet, you just have to make sure it's the outermost element. This can save you from loading more files than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

We use it on our project and never found it to work.

create an external css file of which is not managed by less. The less css file will be able to access the font-face.

Answer (score 0):

So I added a simple @media print { .no-print {display:none;}} into the following referenced .less file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="http://worldMaps.org/maps/styles/growth.less">
```

and it wouldn't work.  However, our css guru pointed out that .lesses default is to use media type of screen, so if you change your referenced less link to

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="http://worldMaps.org/maps/styles/growth.less" media="all">
```

Then suddenly the @media print in the less file will get picked up and start working per normal.

Hopefully this helps someone else as confused as I was.