# 2 calls of a mixin less function with different parameters, have the same result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less, dotless

I call a mixin less function twice with different parameters but the result is the same and created by first parameters. There is a example:

**Input:**

```
.font-face (@fontName, @fontFileName)
{
    @font-face {
        font-family: @fontName;
        src: url("../../fonts/@{fontFileName}.eot");
        src: url("../../fonts/@{fontFileName}.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
             url("../../fonts/@{fontFileName}.woff") format("woff"),
             url("../../fonts/@{fontFileName}.ttf") format("truetype");
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}

.font-face ("BMitra", "BMitra");
.font-face ("BMitraBold", "BMitraBold");
```

**Output:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "BMitra";
  src: url("../../fonts/BMitra.eot");
  src: url("../../fonts/BMitra.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../../fonts/BMitra.woff") format("woff"), url("../../fonts/BMitra.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "BMitra";
  src: url("../../fonts/BMitra.eot");
  src: url("../../fonts/BMitra.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../../fonts/BMitra.woff") format("woff"), url("../../fonts/BMitra.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

What's the problem?
I use dotless in a ASP .Net MVC 3.0 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad news: [@media and @font-face support in LessCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474477/media-and-font-face-support-in-lesscss). '@font-face' is not really supported yet with LESS CSS :(

Comment: OK :( . I created a function for each font without any parameter and the result is correct now.
for example: .fontMitra
{
 @font-face {
  font-family: BMitra;
  src: url("../../fonts/BMitra.eot");
  src: url("../../fonts/BMitra.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../../fonts/BMitra.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../../fonts/BMitra.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
 }
}

Comment: That thread is pretty old.. we have done a lot to improve and @font-face should now be working properly..

Comment: Dear Tigraine , I use your last version. Do You have another solution to use @font-face?

Comment: See the response from Luke Page

Answer (score 2):

Both @media and @font-face are supported by both less.js and dotless in the current version.

However putting @font-face blocks in through a mixin is relatively new territory - there looks like a bug.

[edit]

There is already a [bug for less.js](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/699) which has a [work-around](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/699#issuecomment-5193515).

[Edit 2]

This is now fixed in dotless main.